# How to get the root of the node given a random TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

Given a random TreeViewItem from a tree, how do I retrieve the granddaddy, er root of the node?

I am using this to highlight the root upon clicking a child item.

```
private void TreeViewDecode_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     TreeViewItem treeViewItem = GetSexyGrandDaddy(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
     ...
}
private static TreeViewItem GetSexyGrandDaddy(DependencyObject source)
{
        if (source != null && source is TreeViewItem)
        {
            TreeViewItem root = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source) as TreeViewItem;

            while (root.Parent != null)
            {
                root = root.Parent as TreeViewItem;
            }
            return root as TreeViewItem;
        }
        return null;
}
```

Edit: Code updated still doesn't work

Comment: first suggestion: rename your method to`GetSexySugarDaddy`. :>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with root you mean the 'Parent' i guess,

look at [TreeViewItem.Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.parent.aspx)

**UPDATE**
look at this code:

use

```
    e.Source
```

instead of

```
    e.OrginalSource
```

---

```
    private void treeView1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem treeViewItem = GetSexyGrandDaddy(e.Source as DependencyObject);
        if (treeViewItem != null)
        {
            //do highlight...
        }
    }

    private static TreeViewItem GetSexyGrandDaddy(DependencyObject source)
    {
        TreeViewItem sugarDad = source as TreeViewItem;
        if (sugarDad != null)
        {
            while (sugarDad.Parent as TreeViewItem != null)
                sugarDad = sugarDad.Parent as TreeViewItem;
        }
        return sugarDad;
    }
```

Comment: Not the immediate parent, I mean the very root.

Comment: then you should iterate recursively up till the one treeViewItem has no Parent

Comment: @I46kok then loop till parent is null

Comment: @codeteq Wow this works superb. Thanks a lot. Can I get a brief explanation why OriginalSource doesn't work though?

Comment: OrginalSource returns/is in this case the TextBlock used to Display the Header of the TreeViewItem

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
TreeViewItem root = treeViewItem;
while( root.Parent != null )
{
    root = root.Parent;
}
// now "root" contains the root of you tree...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the parents until the parent is null. then you have the root-node.

```
TreeNode root = node.Parent;
while(root != null)
root = root.Parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private static TreeViewItem GetSexyGrandDaddy(DependencyObject source)
{
    if (source != null && source is TreeViewItem)
    {
        TreeViewItem root = source as TreeViewItem;

        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(root);
        while (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent is TreeViewItem) root = parent as TreeViewItem;
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }

        return root as TreeViewItem;
    }
    return null;
}
```